# how to get publications from medium account where user is either editor or writer

Tags: medium.com-publishing-api

Currently the API `GET https://api.medium.com/v1/users/{{userId}}/publications` will return the publications where user has a role of "editor" or "writer" along with a maximum of 200 other publications the user follows or has other relationships with.

How to get only those publications user has a role of "editor" or "writer" ??